# Is there a way to disable the keybinding for quick save and quick load in Skyrim?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I haven't ever used Quick Save or Quick Load and I'd like to free up the function keys that they're using. I know I can assign them to other keys instead but I have a lot of mods and most of those keys on my keyboard are already used up. Is there a way to "dis-assign" so that they don't have anything mapped to them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I found this mod "[Interface Hard Coded Key Tweaks](http://www.nexusmods.com/skyrim/mods/88/?)" by crazy-g on the Nexus Mods website which seem to have worked!

Comment: I didn't submit Goku's answer, becuase I don't have my game with me to confirm right now, but I'm pretty sure that's correct. Does that not work for you?

Comment: @DCShannon I mentioned, that I have a lot of mods and most of my keys are already bound to one or another. If anything, I'm trying to remove Quick Save and Quick Load since I need more space for a newer mod I added.

Comment: If you say so. That sounds like an absurd number of button bindings.

Comment: How many fingers do you have? :P

Answer (score 2):

Open the Quest Journal, go to settings on the system tab, and select controls. From there you can bind quick-save to a key on a far side of the keyboard you don't use, like on the number pad or an  obscure punctuation key.

Comment: Like I said on my question, I have a lot of mods and most of the keys on my keyboard is already bound to something or another so I'm starting to run out of free keys to bind. Since I don't ever use Quick Save or Quick Load, I'd rather the buttons they occupy be freed up for something else.

Comment: @user400424 If you really don't have any extra buttons, you could get a new mouse with the weird extra buttons and bind it to one of those. If you can't do it any other way, I suggest  using mods or modding Skyrim yourself

Comment: @user400424: Seriously, you're already using backslash and equals?